# Tkinter have a listbox list with checkbox and icon

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a listbox using tkinter but the list should be with checkbox for each item and icon at the head of selection.

Any idea how to add such attribute

Please advice
Thanks

```
from tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

top = Tk()

Lb1 = Listbox(top)
Lb1.insert(1, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(4, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")

Lb1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a listbox, instead of 6 checkboxes stacked on top of each other?

Comment: You should probably use check boxes. They are a widget of thir own. If you really want to, you can put them int a frame and set a scroll bar to scroll through the check boxes in the frame.